# Kaminari and Capybara conflict

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, kaminari

I seem to have some sort of conflict between the page method of capybara and the page method of Kaminari.

That's what I guessed, anyway, here is the error :

```
Failure/Error: before { sign_in_as user }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./app/models/feed.rb:9:in `microposts'
     [Rest of the backtrace]
```

The code sample :

```
class Feed
    def microposts(opts = { urgent: false })                                                                
      urgent = opts[:urgent]                                                                                
      p Microposts.where(id: 1).page # <Capybara::Session>                                                                         
      p Microposts.where(id: 1).page(1) # Error
    end
end
```

If I remove the pagination, the test works fine.

I don't understand how this is possible, I guess Capybara is adding the "page" method to the Object scope, but as Kaminari add its `page` method to ActiveRecord::Base (if I recall correctly) it should override Capybara's one.

I did not see anyone having this kind of trouble, how is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Capybara 2.x

My feature specs are in the `spec/feature directory`. I realised from reading the Capybara documentation that there is no need to include the `Capybara::DSL` in your `spec_helper` if your using the features directory. It's already included.

There is a warning given if you `include Capybara::DSL` in the `spec_helper` that it will pollute the global namespace and this is exactly why it's a bad idea!

[Check out this rspec-rails page on Capybara for details](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Capybara.md)

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of a hack but I was able to work around the problem (where Capybara 'pollutes' the object space) by undef-ing the method in my spec:

```
# Capybara adds a 'page' method to the Object class which conflicts with the Kaminari scope
# Remove it here to allow things to work
Object.send :undef_method, :page
```

I have traced back where this is happening and essentially:

1. The #page method comes from Capybara::DSL
2. The Capybara::DSL method is included into the Object class via RSpec's #configure.include method (see lib/capybara/rspec.rb).
3. RSpec then includes it into the 'group', however I believe this is where it drops into Object.

The solution here might just be to change the name of the method in Capybara, but I guess thats not a decision I'm willing to make :)

Comment: Well I finally changed Kaminari to will_paginate, but thanks for the insights :)